# Set a post expiration and delete a post when expirate

Tags: posts, functions, date, wp-update-post

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to delete an article when the date of the day is equal or superior than a date filled in a custom ACF field.

I wrote the function below that I placed in my single.php in order to test it. It works, except that you must be reading the article in question for this function to execute (pretty logical actually).

What I want is that this function runs itself on all the articles, automatically, without having to go to the articles. This is where It's difficult for me, I often use plugins to do things like that.

Could you show me some ways to achieve the desired result? I'm really looking for improve my back-end skills using Wordpress, so I'm not asking particulary for a ready-made solution but ways to guide my work.

Here's the function :

```
/**
 * Draft after expiration
 */

function draft_the_post(){
    $expire_date = get_field( "field_5cef86384e5f2" );
    $actual_date = date("d-m-Y");
    $postid = $post->ID;

    if ($expire_date <= $actual_date) {
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'    =>  $postid,
            'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));
    } else {
        echo "Not same date or inferior than today";
    };
}
```

Oh and, excuse my english I'm French :-)

I thank you in advance,
willwoody.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use **WordPress Cron** and schedule your event. Also you should consider adding real cron job as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594963/replace-the-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cronjob-every-30-minutes) for better precision.

1.) I modified your `draft_the_post` function to support parameter. So now we can specify which post and also i updated the portion that checking the time.

2.) `dg_cron_schedule_delete_posts` will schedule the hook if it's not scheduled when init hook is fired. I set it to `hourly` for better precision but you can also set it to `daily`. Note: If you are doing this with plugin it's better to use the activation hook and schedule it here.

3.) `dg_delete_posts_handler` is where the deletion is handled. It goes through all the posts and calls the function `maybe_draft_the_post` on each. Note: This queries all the posts so depending of how big is your data this may cause performance issues. I suggest implementing some kind of queue but this should be a good starting point.

```
/**
 * Function that will draft specific post on specific conditions
 *
 * @param \WP_Post $_post
 */
function maybe_draft_the_post( $_post ) {
    $expire_date = get_field( "your_field_name" );
    // Bail if no expire date set.
    if ( ! $expire_date ) {
        return;
    }
    $expire_date = strtotime( $expire_date );
    $actual_date = time();
    if ( $expire_date <= $actual_date ) {
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $_post->ID,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ) );
    }
}

/**
 * Register cron event on init action
 */
function dg_cron_schedule_delete_posts() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'dg_delete_posts' );
    if ( $timestamp == false ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'dg_delete_posts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'dg_cron_schedule_delete_posts' );

/**
 * Handle deletion of posts periodically.
 * - Loop through the posts and call the draft_the_post function.
 */
function dg_delete_posts_handler() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $_post ) {
        maybe_draft_the_post( $_post );
    }
}
add_action( 'dg_delete_posts', 'dg_delete_posts_handler' );
```

Comment: Hi @gdarko, this snippet looks great but can you say, how to edit it for case that someone will need to expire posts automatically after X days from publishing date? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your theme `functions.php` file

Checks if the post has an expiration date, and if so, it schedules an event to delete the post after the specified expiration date.

The `delete_expired_post` function is hooked to the `delete_expired_post_event` action, and it deletes the post when the scheduled event is triggered

```
// Schedule event when a post is published or updated
function schedule_post_expiration_event($ID, $post) {
    $expiration_date = get_post_meta($ID, 'expiration_date', true);

    // Check if the post has an expiration date
    if ($expiration_date) {
        // Convert expiration date to timestamp
        $timestamp = strtotime($expiration_date);

        // Schedule an event to delete the post after the expiration date
        wp_schedule_single_event($timestamp, 'delete_expired_post_event', array($ID));
    }
}

add_action('publish_post', 'schedule_post_expiration_event', 10, 2);
add_action('save_post', 'schedule_post_expiration_event', 10, 2);

// Delete post when the scheduled event is triggered
function delete_expired_post($post_id) {
    wp_delete_post($post_id, true);
}

add_action('delete_expired_post_event', 'delete_expired_post');
```

Comment: Does that create a new scheduled delete for every update or save? What if I set a post to expire tomorrow and then change my mind to make it expire next week instead? Won't the event to delete it tomorrow still exist?